# shell scripting checking python version

Tags: python, shell, cygwin

I have the following shell script to query the python version. It gives me an error stating `"Integer expression expected"` on the if-statement.

```
#!/bin/bash


PYTHON_VERSION=`python -c 'import sys; print("%i" % (sys.hexversion<0x03000000))'`

echo $PYTHON_VERSION

if [ $PYTHON_VERSION -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "fine!"
fi
```

'echo $PYTHON_VERSION' prints out '0', so why dosn't the if-statement work?

EDIT: I am using Windows and Cygwin

Comment: Could you clairify what os and shell you're using? I tried it under OS X with bash and zsh, works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question.  For me it's working fine.  You always should quote evaluated variables (`"$X"` instead of `$X`); maybe that fixes your error.

But I propose to use the result of the python script instead of its output:

```
#!/bin/bash
if python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(1 if sys.hexversion<0x03000000 else 0)'
then
    echo "Fine!"
fi
```

If you like to stay in the shell completely, you also can use the `--version` option:

```
case "$(python --version 2>&1)" in
    *" 3."*)
        echo "Fine!"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Wrong Python version!"
        ;;
esac
```

Maybe that's more readable.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it doesn't work is because the result stored in $PYTHON_VERSION is not an integer, so your equality test is being done with two different types.

You can change the if to:

```
if [ $PYTHON_VERSION -eq "0" ]; then
     echo "fine!"
fi
```

or you can just do:

```
if [ $PYTHON_VERSION = 0 ]; then
```

Comment: ok, I thought bash would convert between string-to-int and int-to-string implicitly?

Comment: It does, the problem is not with the conversion but how -eq is interpreting the expression. There are some cases you need to have: if [[ ]] instead of if [ ], or -eq wont do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible solution

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
else:
    raw_input = input
```

this is from an example I had from sleekxmpp, but it does what you need I believe.

Comment: Isn't his problem on the shell side?